# Actualizar Script Datatable mediante una consulta q devuelve un JSON

Tags: datatable

Hace rato que vengo investigando sobre el tema y la verdad que no le encuentro la vuelta. Mi idea es, mediante la utilización del `Script Datatable` generar una tabla que la cargo mediante un `json`, hasta ahí venimos perfectos, el problema me surge cuando quiero actualizar la tabla ingresando una fecha en un `input`, y que los datos mostrados mediante una consulta `SQL`, se actualicen a la correspondiente fecha que ingreso manualmente.

Espero haber sido claro y que me puedan ayudar! Gracias!

**Editando Agrego parte del código**
Código `HTML` donde genero la tabla

```
<table id="example" class="display table table-fixed">
            <!-- Creacion de la tabla de Indicadores -->
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="indicador_t" rowspan="2">Indicador</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Max/Min/<br>Ran</th>
                <th class="acu_mes" colspan="4">Mes actual (Al día)</th>
                <th rowspan="2" class="ancho_mes">Meta Mensual</th>
                <th class="acu_ejercicio" colspan="3">Acumulado ejercicio (Al día)</th>
                <th rowspan="2" class="ancho_anual">Meta Anual</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Real</th>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Meta</th>
                <th>Cumplimiento</th>
                <th>Real</th>
                <th>Meta</th>
                <th>Cumplimiento</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
          </table>
```

`Script` donde genero tabla a partir de `Datatable`, observaran que hago un agrupamiento según una agrupación determinada.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var datatable = $('#example').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 30,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: {
            url: 'calculos_indicadores.php',
            dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
              { "data": "nombre",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                  if (oData.descripcion != null) {
                    $(nTd).html("<a target='_blank' class='tooltips' href=detalle_indicador.php?id_indicador="+oData.id_indicador+">"+oData.nombre+"<span>"+oData.descripcion+"</span></a>");
                  }else{
                    $(nTd).html("<a target='_blank' href=detalle_indicador.php?id_indicador="+oData.id_indicador+">"+oData.nombre+"</a>");
                  }
                }
              },
              {data:"accion"},
              { "data": "valorActual",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                  if (oData.origen_de_datos == 'excel' && oData.valorOk == 0 && oData.forma_agregacion != 'proporcion') {
                    $(nTd).html("<a class='tooltips class_a_href' href='#'><u>"+oData.valorActual+" "+oData.unidad_medida+"</u><span>Última Actualización:"+oData.ultimaActualizacion+"</span></a>");
                  }else{
                    $(nTd).html("<a class='tooltips class_a_href' href='#'>"+oData.valorActual+" "+oData.unidad_medida+"<span>Última Actualización:"+oData.ultimaActualizacion+"</span></a>");
                  }
                }
              },
              {data:"nombre_area"},
              { "data": "valorObjetivoDiario",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                  if (oData.frecuencia_actualizacion != 'mensual') {
                    $(nTd).html(oData.valorObjetivoDiario);
                  }else{
                    $(nTd).html("-");
                  }
                }
              },
              { "data": "variacion",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                  if (oData.accion != 'Ran') {
                    if (oData.tiene_alarmas == 't') {
                      if (oData.accion == 'Max') {
                        $(nTd).html("<a class='tooltips class_a_href' href='#'>"+oData.variacion+" %<span>Amarillo: "+oData.luzAmarilla+" %&nbsp;||&nbsp;Verde: "+oData.luzVerdeDer+" %</span></a>");
                      }else if (oData.accion == 'Min'){
                        $(nTd).html("<a class='tooltips class_a_href' href='#'>"+oData.variacion+" %<span>Amarillo: "+oData.luzAmarillaDer+" %&nbsp;||&nbsp;Verde: "+oData.luzVerdeDer+" %</span></a>");
                      }
                    }else{
                      $(nTd).html(oData.variacion);
                    }
                  }else{
                    if (oData.tiene_alarmas == 't') {
                      $(nTd).html("<a class='tooltips class_a_href' href='#'>"+oData.variacion+" %<span>Amarillo Inferior: "+oData.luzAmarilla+" %&nbsp;||&nbsp;Rango Verde: "+oData.luzVerde+" %&nbsp;-&nbsp;"+oData.luzVerdeDer+" %&nbsp;||&nbsp;Amarillo Superior: "+oData.luzAmarillaDer+" %</span></a>");
                    }else{
                      $(nTd).html(oData.variacion);
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {data:"valor_objetivo"},
              {data:"acumuladoEjericioReal"},
              {data:"acumuladoEjericioTotal"},
              {data:"desvio",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                  if (oData.tiene_alarmas == 't') {
                    $(nTd).html(oData.desvio+" %");
                  }else{
                    $(nTd).html(oData.desvio);
                  }
                }
              },
              {data:"acumuladoEjericioRealTotal"}
            ],
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                /* Append the grade to the default row class name */
                if ( aData.valor_estado == 1 )
                {
                  $('td:eq(4)', nRow).css('background-color', '#E68282');
                  $('td:eq(4)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');

                }else if (aData.valor_estado == 0.5) {
                  $('td:eq(4)', nRow).css('background-color', '#FCDF6A');
                  $('td:eq(4)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                }else{
                  $('td:eq(4)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                }

                if (aData.estado_acumulado == 1) {
                  $('td:eq(8)', nRow).css('background-color', '#E68282');
                  $('td:eq(8)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                }else if (aData.estado_acumulado == 0.5) {
                  $('td:eq(8)', nRow).css('background-color', '#FCDF6A');
                  $('td:eq(8)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                }else{
                  $('td:eq(8)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                }
            },
              "columnDefs": [
                  { "visible": false, "targets": 3},
                  {"targets": [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ], "className": "text-center"}
              ],
              "language": {"sSearch": "Buscar :  "},
              "order": [[ 3, 'asc' ]],
              "displayLength": 300,
              "paging":   false,
              "info":     false,
              "scrollY":        "500px",
              "scrollCollapse": true,
              "paging":         false,
              "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
                  var api = this.api();
                  var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
                  var last=null;

                  api.column(3, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                      if ( last !== group ) {
                          $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                              '<tr class="group"><td colspan="10" style="font-weight: bold;">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                          );

                          last = group;
                      }
                  } );
              }
          } );

          // Order by the grouping
          $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
              var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
              if ( currentOrder[0] === 3 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
                  table.order( [ 3, 'desc' ] ).draw();
              }
              else {
                  table.order( [ 2, 'asc' ] ).draw();
              }
          } );
      } );
```

**Hasta acá todo perfecto**, ahora mi idea es agregar a partir del `script` anterior que mediante la selección de algún campo, que puede ser una fecha en un `input`, actualice la tabla con los datos de la consulta nueva a partir de la fecha que se pasa.
E buscado muchos ejemplos e investigado pero no e podido dar con la solución a éste problema.

Comment: Deberías poner lo que has intentado, para poder ayudarte

Comment: Pon tu código HTML, JS y un ejemplo de la respuesta que te trae el backend, por favor